# What is the fastest way to programmatically check the well-formedness of XML files in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, well-formed

I have large batches of XHTML files that are manually updated. During the review phase of the updates I would like to programmatically check the well-formedness of the files.
I am currently using a **XmlReader**, but the time required on an average CPU is much longer than I expected.

The XHTML files range in size from 4KB to 40KB and verifying takes several seconds per file. Checking is essential but I would like to keep the time as short as possible as the check is performed while files are being read into the next process step.

Is there a faster way of doing a simple XML well-formedness check? Maybe using external XML libraries?

---

I can confirm that validating "regular" XML based content is lightning fast using the XmlReader, and as suggested the problem seems to be related to the fact that the XHTML DTD is read each time a file is validated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Note that in addition to the DTD, corresponding .ent files (xhtml-lat1.ent, xhtml-symbol.ent, xhtml-special.ent) are also downloaded.

Since ignoring the DTD completely is not really an option for XHTML as the well-formedness  is closely linked to allowed HTML entities (e.g., a &nbsp; will promptly introduce validation errors when we ignore the DTD).

---

The problem was solved by using a **custom XmlResolver** as suggested, in combination with local (embedded) copies of both the DTD and entity files.

I will post the solution here once I cleaned up the code

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  Would you mind posting your code solution to this?

Comment: @STLDeveloper I implemented the suggestion in the following code (VB.NET): [ValidateXMLClass.vb](https://visualqa.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#visualQA/ValidateXMLClass.vb). The required .dtd, .ent, and .mod files are (locally) included as embedded resources to speedup validation.
The code is called as follows:
'Dim validateFile As New ValidateXMLClass
validateFile.fileIn = tgtFile
If Not validateFile.wellFormed Then ... '

Comment: Thank for making available code after such a long time has passed from your original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect that `XmlReader` with `while(reader.Read)() {}` would be the fastest *managed* approach. It certainly shouldn't take **seconds** to read 40KB... what is the input approach you are using?

Do you perhaps have some external (schema etc) entities to resolve? If so, you might be able to write a custom `XmlResolver` (set via `XmlReaderSettings`) that uses locally cached schemas rather than a remote fetch...

The following does ~300KB virtually instantly:

```
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.CloseOutput = false;
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("xml");
            for (int i = 0; i < 15000; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteElementString("value", i.ToString());
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ms.Length + " bytes");
        ms.Position = 0;
        int nodes = 0;
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms))
        {
            while (reader.Read()) { nodes++; }
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} nodes in {1}ms", nodes,
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: This is basically what i am using now. I am reading the files directly (i also tried first reading them into a FileStream, but this does not change much). I set the XmlWriterSettings .ProhibitDtd to False.

Comment: I will have a look and check if the problem is in the referenced DTD and namespaces.

Comment: Like you indicated the problem seems to be the XHTML DTD.
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 2):

Create an `XmlReader` object by passing in an `XmlReaderSettings` object that has the `ConformanceLevel.Document`.

This will validate well-formedness.

This [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel) should explain the details.

Comment: I tried adding the ConformanceLevel.Document to the settings, but there was no noticeable speed increase.

Comment: This is one of the fastest methods. As Marc implied, your speed problem is likely due to some other reason. You should edit your post to include the code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

On my fairly ordinary laptop, reading a 250K XML document from start to finish with an `XmlReader` takes 6 milliseconds.  Something else besides just parsing XML is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is likely the suggested DTD that is being used for every check.

Answer (score 1):

i know im necro posting but i think this could be a solution

1. use HTML Tidy to clear your xml. set the option to remove the doctype
2. then read the generated xhtml/xml from tidy.

here's a same code

```
public void GetDocumentStructure(int documentID)
    {
        string scmRepoPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SCMRepositoryFolder"];
        string docFilePath = scmRepoPath + "\\" + documentID.ToString() + ".xml";

        string docFilePath2 = scmRepoPath + "\\" + documentID.ToString() + "_clean.xml";

        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.Options.MakeClean = true;
        tidy.Options.NumEntities = true;
        tidy.Options.Xhtml = true;
        // this option removes the DTD on the generated output of Tidy
        tidy.Options.DocType = DocType.Omit;

        FileStream input = new FileStream(docFilePath, FileMode.Open);            
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        TidyMessageCollection msgs = new TidyMessageCollection();
        tidy.Parse(input, output, msgs);            
        output.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        XmlReader rd = XmlReader.Create(output);            
        int node = 0;

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (rd.Read())
        {                
            ++node;                
        }
        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Duration was : " + watch.Elapsed.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the bottleneck is most likely not the XmlReader.

Check if you wouldn't happen to do a lot of string concatenation without a stringbuilder.

That can really nuke your performance.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the DTD being re-read every check (when using regular XML files instead of XHTML files the checks run fast as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm pretty lazy ... so I look for .NET libraries that already solve the problem.  Try using the `DataSet.ReadXML()` function and catch the exceptions. It does a pretty amazing job of explaining the XML format errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function for verifying strings/fragments

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function IsValidXMLFragment(ByVal xmlFragment As String, Optional Strict As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    IsValidXMLFragment = True

    Dim NameTable As New Xml.NameTable

    Dim XmlNamespaceManager As New Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(NameTable)
    XmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
    XmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

    Dim XmlParserContext As New Xml.XmlParserContext(Nothing, XmlNamespaceManager, Nothing, Xml.XmlSpace.None)

    Dim XmlReaderSettings As New Xml.XmlReaderSettings
    XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel = Xml.ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    XmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = Xml.ValidationType.Schema
    If Strict Then
        XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = (XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags Or XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema)
        XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = (XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags Or XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings)
    Else
        XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None
        XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = (XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags Or XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes)
    End If

    AddHandler XmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler, Sub() IsValidXMLFragment = False
    AddHandler XmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler, AddressOf XMLValidationCallBack

    Dim XmlReader As Xml.XmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(New IO.StringReader(xmlFragment), XmlReaderSettings, XmlParserContext)
    While XmlReader.Read
        'Read entire XML
    End While
End Function
```

I'm using this function for verifying files:

```
Public Function IsValidXMLDocument(ByVal Path As String, Optional Strict As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    IsValidXMLDocument = IO.File.Exists(Path)
    If Not IsValidXMLDocument Then Exit Function

    Dim XmlReaderSettings As New Xml.XmlReaderSettings
    XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel = Xml.ConformanceLevel.Document
    XmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = Xml.ValidationType.Schema
    If Strict Then
        XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = (XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags Or XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema)
        XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = (XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags Or XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings)
    Else
        XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.None
        XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags = (XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags Or XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes)
    End If
    XmlReaderSettings.CloseInput = True

    AddHandler XmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler, Sub() IsValidXMLDocument = False
    AddHandler XmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler, AddressOf XMLValidationCallBack

    Using FileStream As New IO.FileStream(Path, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Using XmlReader As Xml.XmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(FileStream, XmlReaderSettings)
            While XmlReader.Read
                'Read entire XML
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```