# How to check whether a file is parseable using XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I want to modify some xml files from a given location and I have two methods to do so

`Method1`-->using XDocument to parse and modify the file

`Method2`-->using Regex to parse and modify the file

But some files that I want to modify are not a valid xml, so how do I efficiently check for each of the files whether they are modifiable using `XDocument` or not and perform the operations accordingly like

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(location, "*.xml",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string file in filesindirectory)
{
    if(//file is readable/modifiable using XDocument)
    {
        //perform Method1
    }
    else
    {
        //perform Method2
    }
}
```

Comment: use `XDocument.parse` if it fails with exception that means it is not valid to be parsed via `XDocument`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad is there a better way of checking wihout using an exception

Comment: I can't think of any way of knowing if it's good without trying it.  Kind of like compiling source code.  You have to let something read the code to know if it has errors.  It can be a light weight linter, intellisense, or a full compile, but if you don't look at the contents, how are you going to know if they're good or not?  Same here.  You pretty much have to initiate a parse before you know if it's going to work.  Parsing is also the method by which we determine the cause of failure of a parse.  You gotta parse it.

Comment: This was asked before.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704586/testing-whether-or-not-something-is-parseable-xml-in-c-sharp